# pandas dataframe.sum() result has changed?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code, last used a few months ago:

```py
opendf = pd.DataFrame(
    rdbin[0],
    columns=[
        "highpoint_sum",
        "highpoint_mean",
        "highpoint diff_sum",
        "highpoint diff_mean",
        "name",
        "bin",
    ],
)
opendf.index = opendf["bin"]
opendf.drop(
    columns=["highpoint_sum", "highpoint_mean", "highpoint diff_mean", "name", "bin"],
    inplace=True,
)
opendf["Bresser_sum"] = brbinarr[:, 2]
opendf["open gauge_sum"] = rdbin[21][:, 2]
opendf["br_open_sum"] = opendf[["Bresser_sum", "open gauge_sum"]].sum(
    axis=1, min_count=1
)
```

Which used to result in the column 'br_open_sum' having NaN when cols 'Bresser_sum' and 'open gauge_sum' were both NaN.

```
                    highpoint diff_sum Bresser_sum open gauge_sum br_open_sum
bin                                                                          
2021-07-19 00:00:00                0.0         NaN            NaN        None
2021-07-19 01:00:00                0.0         NaN            NaN        None
2021-07-19 02:00:00                0.0         NaN            NaN        None
2021-07-19 03:00:00                0.0         NaN            NaN        None
2021-07-19 04:00:00                0.0         NaN            NaN        None
2021-07-19 05:00:00                0.0         NaN            NaN        None
2021-07-19 06:00:00                0.0         NaN            NaN        None
2021-07-19 07:00:00                0.0         NaN            NaN        None
2021-07-19 08:00:00                0.0         NaN            NaN        None
2021-07-19 09:00:00                0.0         NaN            NaN        None
2021-07-19 10:00:00                0.0         NaN            NaN        None
2021-07-19 11:00:00                0.0           0            NaN           0
2021-07-19 12:00:00                0.0         0.0            NaN         0.0
2021-07-19 13:00:00                0.0         0.0            NaN         0.0
2021-07-19 14:00:00                0.0         0.0            NaN         0.0
2021-07-19 15:00:00                0.0         0.0            NaN         0.0
2021-07-19 16:00:00                0.0         0.0            NaN         0.0
2021-07-19 17:00:00                0.0         0.0            NaN         0.0
2021-07-19 18:00:00                0.0         0.0            NaN         0.0
2021-07-19 19:00:00                0.0         0.0            NaN         0.0
2021-07-19 20:00:00                0.0         0.0            NaN         0.0
2021-07-19 21:00:00                0.0         0.0            NaN         0.0
2021-07-19 22:00:00                0.0         0.0            NaN         0.0
2021-07-19 23:00:00                0.0         0.0            NaN         0.0
```

Now when I run the code with nothing changing in the data, but I have upgraded from python 3.9 to 3.11, I get 'None' (a NoneType object) in the column (as shown above)

How do I get the .sum() statement to return to previous behaviour? I have read the documentation [pandas dataframe.sum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)and tried all combinations of skipna, numeric_only and min_count.

Replacing the 'None' with NaN would be another alternative, I tried using .fillna() but it threw up a load of errors!

Answer (score 0):

With the following toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        "col2": [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN],
        "col3": [None, None, "0.0"],
    }
)

print(df)
# Output

   col1  col2  col3
0   0.0   NaN  None
1   0.0   NaN  None
2   0.0   NaN   0.0
```

You can use Pandas [to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) method to convert `None` values:

```py
df["col3"] = pd.to_numeric(df["col3"])

print(df)
# Output

   col1  col2  col3
0   0.0   NaN   NaN
1   0.0   NaN   NaN
2   0.0   NaN   0.0
```

Comment: Thankyou @Laurent, this works after the fact, but doesn't answer the main part of the question, which is 'Why is this happening now?' Is it a result of the upgrade to python 3.11?